# Не печатает термопринтер Custom VKP80 II, через приложение на Java

Tags: linux

Установил драйвера для CUSTOM VKP80II пробная страница печатает. Если отправляю через приложение java, останавливает печать. в ErrorLog такая ошибка. "The page setup information was not valid." error log(debug)

Кусок из логов

```
D

 [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Set job-printer-state-message to "The page setup information was not valid.", current level=ERROR
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Unknown operator \"setuserparams\".
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Stack not empty: [ << /UseWTS false >> --setuserparams--
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] PID 38938 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/imagetoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Loaded 98 quirks.
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Printing on printer with URI: usb://CUSTOM%20Engineering/VKP80?serial=VKP80%20200Num.:%200
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] libusb_get_device_list=4
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Device protocol: 2
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Отправка данных на принтер.
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] PID 38939 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertovkp80) stopped with status 1.
D [25/Jan/2023:06:02:40 +0400] [Job 160] Read 17 bytes of print data...


    "D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Loaded 98 quirks.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Printing on printer with URI: usb://CUSTOM%20Engineering/VKP80?serial=VKP80%20200Num.:%200
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] libusb_get_device_list=4
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] STATE: +connecting-to-device
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] STATE: -connecting-to-device
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Page = 215x453; 0,0 to 215,453
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Set job-printer-state-message to "The page setup information was not valid.", current level=ERROR
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Unknown operator \"setuserparams\".
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Stack not empty: [ << /UseWTS false >> --setuserparams--
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] PID 35779 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertovkp80) stopped with status 1.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Printer found with device ID: MFG:CUSTOM Engineering;CMD:ESCPOS;MDL:VKP80;CLS:PRINTER; Device URI: usb://CUSTOM%20Engineering/VKP80?serial=VKP80%20200Num.:%200
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Device protocol: 2
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Отправка данных на принтер.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Read 17 bytes of print data...
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Wrote 17 bytes of print data...
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Sent 17 bytes...
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Waiting for read thread to exit...
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] PID 35778 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/imagetoraster) stopped with status 1.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] PID 35780 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] End of messages
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] printer-state=3(idle)
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] printer-state-message="Отправка данных на принтер."
    D [24/Jan/2023:20:05:07 +0400] [Job 155] printer-state-reasons=none"
```

Comment: Это вы сделали? "Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more."

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос кусок файла или текста для печати вокруг "setuserparams".

Comment: Добавил кусок лога вокруг "setuserparams"